# Laravel Eloquent Sync pivot table except specific values

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I want to use `sync()` for table `client_package` except some values/fields.

It's because I'm displaying `checkboxes` with `client` names, that I want to add to a `package`.
So if User has specific `permission`, he could see specific `clients`, and it's done:

```
<div class="mb-6">
    <label for="package_clients" class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium flex">Bundle Clients:</label>
        <div class="border border-gray-200 rounded-lg">
            <div class="p-4 overflow-auto min-h-40 max-h-96">
            @foreach($clients as $client)
            <p><input type="checkbox" name="package_clients[]" id="client-{{$client->id}}" value="{{ $client->id }}"
            @foreach($package_clients as $package_client)
                @if($client->id == $package_client->id) checked @else @endif
            @endforeach
                />
            <label for="bundle-{{$client->id}}"> {{ $client->name }} </label>
            </p>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

But after `syncing` the list of `clients` assigned to a `package` I got `detached` clients, that are not in the list (the remaining ones from the DataBase).

I want to avoid that, but in my case I can't use `attach()` and `detach()` separately(depending on situation), because User could assign and misallocate multiple `clients` at once.

I want to pass f.e. `array` of Clients, that could not be `detached`. Is that possible?

My way to syncing Clients to Package:

```
$package->clients()->sync($clients);
```

`$clients` is an array of `id's`.

Or there's a option of doing the `sync()` only on that Collection of `clients` not in whole DB?

Answer (score 0):

How about use `syncWithoutDetaching()` instead of `sync()` ?

Edited :

How about using the `wherePivotNotIn()`
example :

```
$package->clients()->wherePivotNotIn('client_id', $clients)->sync($clients);
```

Comment: I thought about using first of all `$package->clients()->detach(Client::whereIn('code`, $privileges)->pluck('id')->toArray()); ` and then attaching the `$clients` array. Would it be good aproach?

Answer (score 0):

```
// it's your array of client's ids
$client_ids = $request->package_clients;

// it's ur clients
$clients = Client::whereIn('id',$client_ids)->get();

// and sync. that's all
$package->clients()->sync($clients);
```